# Trigger an update of the UpdatePanel by a control that is in different ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page with two ContentPlaceHolders.  One has a DropDown and another UpdatePanel with content.

How can I trigger update to the UpdatePanel by the DropDown's selectedItemChanged event when they are in different ContentPlaceholders?

The following would not work since UpdatePanel1 doesn't know about DropDown1:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Some content that needs to be updated here...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

One way is to make an ajax page method that would be called by javascript on the page when DropDown's item is selected. Then in code behind, inside that page method, call UpdatePanel1.Update().

Is there an easier alternative?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx

> The control that the
>   AsyncPostBackTrigger references must
>   be in  the same naming container as
>   the update panel for which it is a 
>   trigger. Triggers that are based on
>   controls in other naming  containers
>   are not supported.

The workaround is to use the UniqueID of the control that the 
trigger is referencing. Unfortunately the UniqueID isn't qualified
until the control has been added to its parent (and its parent 
has been added to its parent, all the way up the control tree).

In your code behind, try:

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = DropDown1.UniqueID,
    EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged", // this may be optional
});
```

Comment: @lucian.jp: remember to place that code as late in the rendering as possible. I forget where atm, but it needs to go after the control hierarchy has been fully constructed.

Comment: This worked for me. I put the code into an override of OnLoad, after the base.OnLoad was executed.

Answer (score 4):

In the code-behind file, you should be able to do:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(dropdown1);
```

Comment: Both your solution and the accepted answer worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce update any of page UpdatePanels by call `updatePanel1.Update()` method on server side.
For example during update updatePanel1 on `button1.Click` call `updatePanel2.Update()`  and both panels will be updated.

Comment: This would not prevent the whole page postback.
If you add the trigger on the load/init to the panel using the UniqueID of the control, only the panel would be updated