# updating second updatepanel using checkbox in first updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two UpdatePanels. One `UpdatePanel` has a `CheckBox` and a `UserControl`. UserControl has some `TextBoxes`. In other updatepanel, there are few `Labels`.

I have added javascript function to checkbox to hide/show it. I am using Javascript to avoid partial postbacks to server.

I also want to update the second UpdatePanel when checkbox is checked/unchecked or some data is changes in user control's textboxes.

Can I call javascript function as well as server side function on same checkbox ? I tried adding triggers to second updatepanel but they are not fired.

```
updatepanel1
  checkbox 
  usercontrol
    textbox1
    texbox2

updatepanel2
   label1 (updated on change of textbox 1)
   label2 (updated on change of textbox 1)
```

my checkbox markupd looks like this

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShippingSameAsBilling" runat="server" 
     Text="  Ship to same address"
     AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" 
     onclick="return ShowShippingAddress();" 
 />
```

Comment: Don't know about updating from javascript, but have you tried `updatepanel1.Update()` on server side ??

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: So you want to show/hide UpdatePanel2 on CheckBox checked/uncheck(this does `ShowShippingAddress`) and you want to update the Labels when TextBox' Text changed? I yet don't understand why you need the serverside function.

Comment: yes I tried. Actually one when I hookup client function, server function is not called.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy button on the page. Set async postback trigger for the second panel on the button.

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAsync" EventName="Click" />
```

In the check changed of the check box, in javascript call function

```
btnAsync.Click();
```

It will postback the second update panel asynchronously. You can call server side functions from second panel postback or by adding server side click event to dummy button.

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden button in your second updatePanel:

```
<div style="display:none">
   <asp:Button ID="YourButton" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Then click in using your onclick function:

```
function ShowShippingAddress() 
{
     document.getElementById('<%# YourButton.ClientID %>').click()
}
```

That should cause the second to postback and update.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a **trigger** in the second panel to use the event from the checkbox, there are some examples here.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

[Trigger an update of the UpdatePanel by a control that is in different ContentPlaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417131/trigger-an-update-of-the-updatepanel-by-a-control-that-is-in-different-contentpl)

Also, take a look at **knockout.js** or **jquery** for some more elegant solutions...

http://knockoutjs.com/