# AsynchPostBackTrigger still refreshes whole page every OTHER time

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asynchronous

I've just implemented a small `UpdatePanel` with a button outside the panel that modifies the controls within it. Per instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728043/how-to-stop-updatepanel-from-causing-whole-page-postback) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417131/trigger-an-update-of-the-updatepanel-by-a-control-that-is-in-different-contentpl) I have set up a trigger on `Page_Load` that looks like this...

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(item: new AsyncPostBackTrigger
{
    ControlID = Button1.UniqueID
});
```

...in order to allow the button click event to update the panel asynchronously (it was refreshing the whole page before). However, now it works asynch the first time, but every *other* click after that triggers a whole page refresh. I'm pretty confused by that one. Can anyone spot what's wrong? (**Edit:** To clarify, the following represents the refresh results of a series of clicks starting after page load: Asynch (good), Whole Page (bad), Asynch, Whole Page, Asynch, Whole Page, etc...)

FYI the form is ASP.NET 4.0 and resides in a SharePoint 2013 visual web part, if that matters.

Comment: Consider change your code to the `aspx` file. Maybe you are doing it in the wrong time. doing it in the `aspx` solve some of those problems.

Comment: @VitorCanova I'll try your suggestion. What is the difference as far as sequencing goes?

Comment: I already had a lot of problems by doing some thing in the wrong method (probably not your case) or in the wrong place in the so used `IsPostBack` `if` statement. When defined in the `aspx` file ASP.NET guarantee it will be called when need, in the moment it is needed and nothing more.

Comment: @thanby, Doing it declaratively (in your aspx) makes sure that the value is assigned at the correct time. If you assign it in your code-behind (i.e. Page_Load) you're overriding that default behavior (which might end up in you NOT assigning it at the correct time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try scriptmanager **EnablePartialRendering** property like this

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" EnablePartialRendering="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>